# VBA Copy whole row to different sheet based on a cell value, to next available row

Tags: excel, vba, rows, copying

I'm a beginner using VBA, I'm trying to copy the whole row of source data 'Search' (see image), into a secondary tab called 'order' if there is any data in column M of the source data (will be numeric - which is why I've tried >0). Both sheets are in the same workbook.

The trick is, I want to paste it onto the next available row in the order tab - without copying over any previously copied rows.

This is my code so far but it isn't copying over the data. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub CopySomeCells()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim DestinationRow As Long
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search")
    Set DestinationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Order")

    DestinationRow = 2
    For SourceRow = 2 To SourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If SourceSheet.Range("M" & SourceRow).Value > 0 Then
            SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 29)).Copy _
                DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationRow, 2)
            DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1
        End If
    Next SourceRow
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set SourceSheet = Nothing
    Set DestinationSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: Database]

Comment: The code is working fine. Check the worksheets and if `M` is the right column. For appending, instead of `DestinationRow = 2` you could use `DestinationRow = DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. Also, remove the last three lines: `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is usually used when applying `PasteSpecial` and the remaining two lines are automatically being done (it's one of VBA's 'jobs') when the procedure exits.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems like it's almost working. The issues being that it isn't pasting the data under the next line, instead it keeps replacing the top couple of lines, with the new 'quantity' data that I'm inputting, but not the correct rest of the data (columns A-L). Instead it is always pulling in the same rows (always  row 2, then 3, then 4, if for example, I put in 3 values in 'quanity')